# MySQLi Tutorials

Tags: mysql, mysqli

I have just finished building my site, and now it's time to finally put a database in it and actually connect it to a database. So far I have downloaded Xampp and installed everything and tested it.

As I was starting to use MySQL, I was told that i should not use it and actually use MySQLi. I tried to find some tutorials but everything is very confusing.

I have found these on YouTube:

- [How Build a Simple HTML Form Using PHP and MySQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wp6Ngpk5XiY)
- [How to create register form in PHP and MySQLi Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6bHu_snHL8)

Do you guys think this is the way to go to create a small database? Or could anyone recommend any other good tutorials around this area to create a login and reg database?

All my database would be doing is allowing people to reg and login, and send some queries etc back to the user. So I am not sure if i should use MySQLi.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the links that you provided, I would suggest looking into PHP's PDO (PHP Data Object). The reason for this is because the mysqli way is getting pretty old at this point.  PDO is relatively simple to use and it has different drivers for different database vendors.  So if you want to switch out your database system for something else, then it is easier to switch with PDO.

Here is a couple tutorials:

- [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
- [Why you Should be using PHP's PDO for Database Access](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

The second tutorial is a little more involved and shows more detail and the first is probably what you're looking for.